# header design issue in pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I wish the header look like these Red Rectangles but my code displays it  overlapped as seen in the below image.
is any other solution to arrange the header

[image]

and my code is

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                {
                    string header = Convert.ToString(Session["Header"]);                       
                    float marginLR = 36;
                    float marginB = 2;
                    float footerHeight = 10;
                    Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetCropBox(i);
                    if (pagesize == null)
                    {
                        pagesize = reader.GetPageSize(i);
                    }
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
                            pagesize.Left + marginLR, pagesize.Top + marginB,
                            pagesize.Right - marginLR, pagesize.Top + marginB + footerHeight
                        );



                    // Phrase ft = new Phrase(footer, blackFont);
                    float marginLR2 = 36;
                    float marginB2 = 2;
                    float footerHeight2 = 10;

                     Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(60, 60, 810, 810);

                    image.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left, rect.Top - image.ScaledHeight);
                    var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
                    image.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(54f);
                    image.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(84f);
                    pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
                    inputImageStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(stamper.GetUnderContent(i));
                    ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect2);
                    ct.AddElement(new Paragraph(header));
                    ct.Go();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wish the header look like these Red Rectangles but my code displays it overlapped

Your code displays it overlapped *because the coordinate ranges you use seem to have been chosen to overlap*.

You set the leftmost **x** coordinate of the image here

```
image.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left, rect.Top - image.ScaledHeight);
```

to `rect.Left` which according to

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
    pagesize.Left + marginLR, pagesize.Top + marginB,
    pagesize.Right - marginLR, pagesize.Top + marginB + footerHeight
);
```

is `pagesize.Left + marginLR`. Your question does not state what `pagesize.Left`, so let's assume the very common value `0` for it. Then due to

```
float marginLR = 36;
```

the leftmost **x** coordinate of the image turns out to be 36.

You scale the image here

```
image.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(84f);
```

to a width of 84. Thus, the rightmost **x** coordinate of the image is 36 + 84 = 120.

The leftmost **x** coordinate of the text is set here

```
ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect2);
```

to the leftmost **x** coordinate of that rectangle which is defined as

```
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(60, 60, 810, 810);
```

Thus, the leftmost **x** coordinate of the text is 60.

---

So you have chosen the image to span **x** coordinate from 36 to 120 and the text to span **x** coordinates starting at 60. *According to your code, therefore, you wanted the image and the text to overlap!*

As a side note, you add the image to the `OverContent` and the text to the `UnderContent`, so you in particular want the image to cover the text.

---

If you actually did not want this overlapping, then you chose inappropriate coordinates.

As the width of the image seems to match the width of those red rectangles, its **x** coordinates seem to be correct. Thus, you should correct your `rect2` definition to have a leftmost **x** coordinate which is a bit larger than the rightmost image x coordinate 120, e.g. 136:

```
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(136, 60, 810, 810);
```

BTW, the rightmost **x** coordinate for the text is chosen here to be 810. That looks very wrong and in particular does not match your red rectangles...

---

Your **y** coordinates are chosen inappropriately, too. E.g. while setting the image position you use its `ScaledHeight`:

```
image.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left, rect.Top - image.ScaledHeight);
```

but shortly thereafter you rescale the height of the image

```
image.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(54f);
```

so the former calculation is based on the wrong height. *Only use the `ScaledHeight` of the image *after* you have finished scaling that image height.*

Concerning the upper **y** coordinate of the text, you explicitly choose it to be 810 in your `rect2` definition. If you want it to start higher, use a larger value.